# Is it possible for monobasic and dibasic potassium phosphate to complete break down into phosphates?

Tags: acid-base, ions

Here is the picture of monobasic potassium phosphate:
[image]

And here is the picture of dibasic potassium phosphate:

[image]

Is it possible for the phosphorous-containing anions to further break down into actual phosphates and floating protons?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  What do you mean by "actual phosphates"?

Answer (score 1):

At basic conditions over pH 10, those *phosphorus-containing anions* can get further deprotonated, as can easily be seen on the corresponding [Wikipedia article on phosphates.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphate#Chemical_properties)

Phosphoric acid $\rightarrow$ Dihydrogen phosphate $\rightarrow$ Hydrogen phosphate $\rightarrow$ Phosphate